# Unique elements in each file

Tags: python, perl, bash, shell

I have 4 files and would like to know elements which are non overlapping (per file) compared to the elements in other files.

File A

```
Vincy
ruby
rome
```

File B

```
Vincy
rome
Peter
```

File C

```
Vincy
Paul
alex
```

File D

```
Vincy
rocky
Willy
```

Any suggestion for one liner in perl, python, shell, bash. The expected output is:

File A: `ruby`, File B: `Peter`, File C: `Paul`, `Alex` File D: `rocky`, `Willy`.

Comment: What would you expect the output to be, here?

Comment: @sven: I gave up that's why i posted.

Comment: @ Sean: File A: ruby, File B: Peter,  File C: Paul, Alex FIle D: rocky, Willy

Comment: All those files match the condition that `all elements are unique to each file`.

Comment: I should reframe the question, I see  my mistake and the mistakes in answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edit after question clarified: Unique elements across all files, and the file in which it occurs:

```
cat File_A File_B File_C File_D |sort | uniq -u | while read line ; do file=`grep -l $line File*` ; echo "$file $line" ; done
```

Edit:

perly way of doing it, will be faster if the files are large:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use autodie;

my $wordHash ;

foreach my $arg(@ARGV){
    open(my $fh, "<", $arg);
    while(<$fh>){
        chomp;
        $wordHash->{$_}->[0] ++;
        push(@{$wordHash->{$_}->[1]}, $arg);
    }
}

for my $word ( keys %$wordHash ){
    if($wordHash->{$word}->[0] eq 1){
        print $wordHash->{$_}->[1]->[0] . ": $word\n"
    }
}
```

execute as:
    myscript.pl filea fileb filec ... filezz

*stuff from before clarification:*
Easy enough with shell commands.  Non repeating elements across all files

```
cat File_A File_B File_C File_D |sort | uniq -u
```

Unique elements across all files

```
cat File_A File_B File_C File_D |sort | uniq
```

Unique elements per file
(edit thanks to @Dennis Williamson)

```
for line in File* ; do echo "working on $line" ; sort $line | uniq ; done
```

Comment: I didn't know about uniq. One more tool in my toolbox, thanks.

Comment: Look at the desired output in the comments.  The OP seems to be looking for the lines occuring only in a single file, grouped by files.  Neither of these solutions does this.

Comment: yeah - answered before he added that unfortunately

Comment: Always fun when they move the goalposts.

Comment: Nice.  You should unquote `"File*"` (caused it to fail on my install) and throw in a final `| sort` for ordered output.  +1.

Comment: You could also move the last version to the top – it's the only one answering the actual question.  Also note that the solution is rather inefficient for bigger files (quadratic runtime), but it should do fine for small files.

Comment: why `ls | while` instead of `for line in File*`?

Comment: because my skills in shell are not as good as they could be! will update

Comment: Be aware that if, for instance, 'ruby' appears twice in file A, it will not appear in the final list; you would have to run uniq on each basis file first.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a quick python script that will do what you ask over an arbitrary number of files:

```
from sys import argv
from collections import defaultdict

filenames = argv[1:]
X = defaultdict(list)
for f in filenames:
    with open(f,'r') as FIN:
        for word in FIN:
            X[word.strip()].append(f)

for word in X:
    if len(X[word])==1:
        print "Filename: %s word: %s" % (X[word][0], word)
```

This gives:

```
Filename: D word: Willy
Filename: C word: alex
Filename: D word: rocky
Filename: C word: Paul
Filename: B word: Peter
Filename: A word: ruby
```

Comment: This solution has linear runtime, so it will be much more efficient than the O(n²) solution in the other answer.

Comment: You should use `with` to open and close files.

Answer (score 1):

Hot needle:

```
import sys
inputs = {}
for inputFileName in sys.args[1:]:
  with open(inputFileName, 'r') as inputFile:
    inputs[inputFileName] = set([ line.strip() for line in inputFile ])
for inputFileName, inputSet in inputs.iteritems():
  print inputFileName
  result = inputSet
  for otherInputFileName, otherInputSet in inputs.iteritems():
    if otherInputFileName != inputFileName:
      result -= otherInputSet
  print result
```

Didn't try it though ;-)

Comment: I always forget about `with open`!. Incorrect as stands, has a syntax error as written. `sys.args` should be `sys.argv`.

Comment: @Hooked: This one also scales worse for a big number of files – it's quadratic in the number of files.  Your solution is the only one that is purely linear in the input size (the combined size of all input files).

Comment: @Hooked: Well, has been the only one.  The Perl solution is also purely linear. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Perl one-liner, readable version with comments:**

```
perl -nlwe '     
    $a{$_}++;     # count identical lines with hash
    push @a, $_;  # save lines in array
    if (eof) { push @b,[$ARGV,@a]; @a=(); }   # at eof save file name and lines
    }{ # eskimo operator, executes rest of code at end of input files
    for (@b) { 
        print shift @$_;                      # print file name
        for (@$_) { print if $a{$_} == 1 };   # print unique lines
    }
' file{A,B,C,D}.txt
```

Note: `eof` is for each individual input file.

**Copy/paste version:**

```
perl -nlwe '$a{$_}++; push @a, $_; if (eof) { push @b,[$ARGV,@a]; @a=(); } }{ for (@b) { print shift @$_; for (@$_) { print if $a{$_} == 1 } }' file{A,B,C,D}.txt
```

**Output:**

```
filea.txt
ruby
fileb.txt
Peter
filec.txt
Paul
alex
filed.txt
rocky
Willy
```

Notes: This was trickier than expected, and I'm sure there's a way to make it prettier, but I'll post this for now and see if I can clean it up.